# Angular - An unhandled exception occurred: spawn UNKNOWN

Tags: angular, npm

In Angular-13 project I have a project that has been working very fine. But suddenly, when I did **ng serve** I got this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: spawn UNKNOWN
See "C:\Users\JOSHU~1.IBE\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-i3hvNX\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The error log gives:

```
[error] Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:700:9)
    at baseOpen (C:\MyProject\LMS-UI\node_modules\open\index.js:205:34)
    at async MergeMapSubscriber.project (C:\MyProject\LMS-UI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\builders\dev-server\index.js:220:21)
```

I did this:

> 1. remove node_modules `rm -rf node_modules` or just delete them
> 2. run `npm i` or `npm i --only=dev`(only when all modules are already installed just need to save the dev dependencies)
> 3. run `ng serve` or `npm start`

But the problem still remains.

How do I resolve the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Which version of NodeJS do you have?

Comment: Try to delete the cache in .angular

Comment: @Alexander -   npm: '8.5.0',
  node: '16.14.2',

Comment: @C.Eggart - I deleted the  cache in .angular but the problem is still there

Comment: I read that an antivirus may interrupt the node proces. If you have one, can you disable it temporarily, try it again and re-enable the antivirus?

Answer (score 1):

Like you can see in the stack trace, the error is thrown by the [`open`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/open) npm package. They have an open GitHub issue where users of the Windows CMD have exactly the same issue like you do: https://github.com/sindresorhus/open/issues/205

A workaround is to use another shell, e.g. PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps, hope it will solve the problem :-

1. Close all the servers if you have started (e.g., JSON server).
2. Remove node_modules folder by running the command :- rm -rf node_modules.
3. Also delete package-lock.json file.
4. Do also run the following command after that :- npm cache clean --force
5. Re-run the command :- npm install
6. Start the server :- ng serve -open