# Angular - How to resolve An unhandled exception occurred: spawn UNKNOWN

Tags: angular

I have Angular-14 project with these features:

node:   v16.15.1

npm:   8.12.1

When I did ng serve--o, I got this error

```
An unhandled exception occurred: spawn UNKNOWN
See "C:\Users\JACOB~1.AKW\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-1F4Fst\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The error log gives:

```
[error] Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:700:9)
    at baseOpen (C:\App\GNS\node_modules\open\index.js:205:34)
    at async MergeMapSubscriber.project (C:\App\GNS\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\builders\dev-server\index.js:220:21)
```

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: ng serve--o is not a command.

Comment: Maybe you mean `ng serve --o` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72211198/angular-an-unhandled-exception-occurred-spawn-unknown